# Sync GPG ~/.gnupg dir between multiple Macs? (MacGPG)

Tags: macos, mac, data-synchronization, gpg

I have [GPG Suite](https://gpgtools.org/) 2020.1 installed on 2 computers, both running macOS 11.0.1.

I would like to sync my GPG keychain and config files between them, so that adding/trusting a key on one machine is reflected on the other. I imagine this should be possible by syncing one or more files from `~/.gnupg`

For the sync mechanism, I will be using [Resilio Sync](https://www.resilio.com/individuals/) (not a public cloud). However, that should be mostly irrelevant; I imagine one could use git, Syncthing, or even Dropbox (risks of storing private keys on a public cloud notwithstanding!)

Can anyone tell me if this is possible, and how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I ended up doing it. It's working for me with macOS 12.3.1 and GPGSuite 2022.1.

##### First, set up the main sync dir (do this on the Mac that has the config you want to replicate)

```sh
# shut down gpg-agent
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent

# set the var below to whatever path you want to use
GPG_SYNC_PATH=$HOME/Sync/gnupg

# move GPG folder
mv ~/.gnupg $GPG_SYNC_PATH

# create symlink
ln -sv $GPG_SYNC_PATH ~/.gnupg

# set permissions
chmod -h 700 ~/.gnupg
find "$GPG_SYNC_PATH" -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find "$GPG_SYNC_PATH" -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;

# reload gpg-agent
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
```

##### Then, configure the other Macs to sync with it

```sh
gpgconf --kill gpg-agent
GPG_SYNC_PATH=$HOME/Sync/gnupg
mv ~/.gnupg ~/.gnupg.old
ln -sv $GPG_SYNC_PATH ~/.gnupg
chmod -h 700 ~/.gnupg
find "$GPG_SYNC_PATH" -type f -exec chmod 600 {} \;
find "$GPG_SYNC_PATH" -type d -exec chmod 700 {} \;
gpg-connect-agent reloadagent /bye
```

*Permissions fix was based on https://superuser.com/questions/954509/what-are-the-correct-permissions-for-the-gnupg-enclosing-folder-gpg-warning*

Comment: Are the two finds relevant on the other Macs? Permissions should get synced from the first Mac I assume.

Comment: @nohillside You're right, but depending on the sync solution in use, permissions aren't always replicated. Can't hurt, could help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is certainly possible. The files in ~/.gnupg are just ordinary text files - there's nothing that "binds" them to one specific machine as such.

You can do it either by adding the files to an already-synced folder, and then linking them into ~/.gnupg - or by choosing ~/.gnupg as the folder where you want data synced to (you can choose that individually for each folder that you sync from Resilio).